# SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 configuration to allow adding users from multiple Domains/forests

Tags: dns, ldap, tridion

We have default installation with Windows authentication in Domain1 and we are manually adding users from Content Manager page by searching users in same Domain1. Recently new Domain2 was added as a Two-way forest transitive. What need to be done to be able to search and add users from Domain2 to Content Manager? when I'm trying to search for users specifying Domain2 in CM - new user page I'm getting an error: Unable to find domain with name "Domain2". Can this be done by using default setup or we need to configure this to use LDAP?

Answer (score 4):

For starters the two domains need to have a full trust relationship with each other (I'm not up to par with forests but here you can find more details about [Active Directory Domains and Trusts](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770299.aspx)). This should allow IIS for being able to authenticate against both domains.

The next step is to make sure that your MTSUser account (or the identity the SDL Tridion Content Manager COM+ application is running under) is a domain account and has read rights on both domains, so it can list the users. That will enable you to search for the users and add them to the CMS.

Comment: So it's not required to go with LDAP configuration?

Comment: No need for LDAP, you should be fine with just trusted domains and a COM+ identity that can browse both domains. IF you have follow up questions on this topic, probably best to ask them on serverfault.com and tag em with tridion.

Comment: I'm still getting this error:                                           Unable to get list of User items.
Unable to find the Windows domain "corp".
Error Code:
0x80040006 (-2147221498)
Call stack:
Tridion.Security.WindowsDomain.GetNetBiosName(String)
Tridion.Security.WindowsDomain..ctor(String)
Tridion.ContentManager.BLFacade.SystemFacade.GetListNonSystemUsersXml(ListFilter,Session)
Tridion.ContentManager.BLFacade.SystemFacade.GetListData(UserContext,EnumListKind,ListColumnFilter,String)
UtilitiesTDS.InternalGetListNonSystemUsers
TDSE.GetListNonSystemUsers

Comment: Still an indication that the MTSUser (or the identity which is running the SDL Tridion Content Manager COM+ application) has no rights to browse/list your corp domain.